# How to rotate a array with x, y values?

Tags: graphing-functions

So i have array that can look like this (javascript for the matter):

```
array = [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: -4, y: 3}]
```

Each of the entrys has a x and y position. What i want to do is essentialy rotate those entrys 90 degrees in one direction.

Whats the simplest way to do this?

Comment: The center of the rotation is $(0,0)$? Counter-clockwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could something like this to perform a counter clockwise $90$ degrees rotation of center $(0,0)$. The point $(x,y)$ is transformed in $(-y,x)$.

```
c=x
x=-y
y=c
```

One liner javascript code:

```
[x, y] = [-y, x];
```

Drawing it should convince you. 
You could look at [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for solutions of broader problems with a different angle for example.

Comment: This rotates 180

Comment: Oops yes I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

What about iterating over the array, converting each pair $(x, y)$ to a complex number, using for instance `Complex.js`, and multiplying by the imaginary unit $i$, which corresponds to a rotation of 90 degrees counterclockwise.